# TikZ intersections slow and failing

Tags: intersection, tikz

I don't find the cause of this slowness in this figure, and it seems it does not do it well.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings,intersections,fpu,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\sz{3}
    \clip circle (\sz);
    \draw[name path=cen]     circle (\sz);
    \draw[name path=pri] (\sz,0)
        node[left] {1}       circle (\sz);
    \draw[name intersections={of=pri and cen},name path=sec]
        (intersection-1)
        node[below left] {2} circle (\sz);
    \draw[name intersections={of=sec and cen},name path=ter]
        (intersection-1)
        node[below right] {3} circle (\sz);
    \draw[name intersections={of=ter and cen},name path=cua]
        (intersection-1)
        node[right] {4}       circle (\sz);
    \draw[name intersections={of=cua and cen},name path=qui]
        (intersection-2)
        node[above right] {5} circle (\sz);
    \draw[name intersections={of=qui and cen},name path=sex]
        (intersection-2)
        node[above left] {6}  circle (\sz);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

It produces the figure:

[image]

I was pursuing this result:

[image]

Comment: Do you actually need intersections? It will be much faster to draw the full circles and clip them.

Comment: Well, I know it is `    \clip circle (10);
    \draw circle (10);
    \draw (60:10) circle (10);
  etc
`
The idea was to experiment intersections and it behaviour has been a bit disappointing.

I have simplified the original based on intersections

Comment: OP has reported this to https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1256.